# While using DOSBox, if I try running my code with debugger it works, while without using debugger my code does not run?

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, masm, x86-16

While using DOSBox, if I try running my code with the debugger it works, while without using debugger my code does not run and execute the way it did when I used debugx. Why does this happen?

The question is:

> Write an ALP that will take in a single user input a number between (0-9). If the user for e.g. enters 5 then the 5th character in file tab.txt must be exchanged with the 5th character in file lab.txt. The size of files is variable but definitely greater than 10 bytes. The user input must not be displayed on the screen.

```
.model tiny
.486
.data

 file db 'lab.txt',0
 handle dw ?
 buffer db 1 dup(?)
 fil db 'tab.txt',0
 han dw ?
 buffer1 db 1 dup(?)
 imp db ?
 .code
 .startup

lea si,imp
mov ah,08h
int 21h
and al,0fh
dec al
mov [si],al

mov ah,3dh
mov al,2
lea dx,file
int 21h
mov handle,ax

mov ah,3dh
mov al,2
lea dx,fil
int 21h
mov han,ax

mov al,0
mov bx,handle
mov cx,0
mov dx,[si]
mov ah,42h
int 21h

mov al,0
mov bx,han
mov cx,0
mov dx,[si]
mov ah,42h
int 21h

mov     ah,03fh
mov     bx,handle
mov     cx,1
lea     dx,buffer
int     21h
mov     ah,03fh
mov     bx,han
mov     cx,1
lea     dx,buffer1
int     21h

mov al,0
mov bx,handle
mov cx,0
mov dx,[si]
mov ah,42h
int 21h

mov al,0
mov bx,han
mov cx,0
mov dx,[si]
mov ah,42h
int 21h

mov     ah,40h
mov     bx,handle
mov     cx,1
lea     dx,buffer1
int     21h

mov     ah,40h
mov     bx,han
mov     cx,1
lea     dx,buffer
int     21h


mov     bx,handle
mov     ah,03eh
int     21h
mov     bx,han
mov     ah,03eh
int     21h

.exit
 end
```

Comment: One obvious error is `mov dx,[si]` which is loading 2 bytes but you only have 1.

Comment: thank you, finally could solve it, didnt realize the error